# Replace NAs with 0 in all numeric columns using data.table in R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, lapply, na

I want to compose code that will replace NAs with 0 in all numeric columns using data.table syntax.

My code is the following:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1:3,NA, NA, NA, 10:12 ), b = c(NA, NA, NA, 20:25), c = c(letters[1 : 7], NA, NA) )

> dt
    a  b  c
1:  1 NA  a
2:  2 NA  b
3:  3 NA  c
4: NA 20  d
5: NA 21  e
6: NA 22  f
7: 10 23  g
8: 11 24 NA
9: 12 25 NA


needed_names <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)]

dt_ <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){if(is.na(x)) 0 else x}), .SDcols = needed_names] 

> dt_
    a b
1:  1 0
2:  2 0
3:  3 0
4: NA 0
5: NA 0
6: NA 0
7: 10 0
8: 11 0
9: 12 0
```

Could you tell me why my code is not working and what I should do to correct it?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can do this with `set` by looping over the numeric columns (`needed_names`) and `set` the elements that are NA specified in `i` to 0

```
for(j in needed_names){
   set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), j=j, value = 0)
}
dt
#    a  b  c
#1:  1  0  a
#2:  2  0  b
#3:  3  0  c
#4:  0 20  d
#5:  0 21  e
#6:  0 22  f
#7: 10 23  g
#8: 11 24 NA
#9: 12 25 NA
```

---

Regarding the OP's code, when there are more than one element, we use `ifelse` or `replace` and also the output should be assigned back to the columns of interest otherwise, we will only the columns specified in the `.SDcols` and will not be updated in the original dataset

```
dt[, (needed_names) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          replace(x, is.na(x), 0)), .SDcols = needed_names]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
num_cols <- sapply(dt, is.numeric)
dt2 <- dt[,num_cols,with=F]
dt <- cbind(dt[,!num_cols, with=F],dt2)
```